# select box outside my form code

Tags: php, forms

I have a select box outside my form, When the users selects an option, the right form is being shown. But I want to send the value of the selected option together with the form.

```
<select id="selection" onchange="showForm()">
<option value="iphone">iPhone</option>
<option value="Android">Android</option>
</select>

<form action="iphone.php" method="post" id="form1">
<input type="text name="username" required>
</form>

<form action="android.php" method="post" id="form2">
<input type="text name="username" required>
</form>
```

**Please note:** This is a simple example, I want to know how you can send the value of the selectbox outside the form.

Comment: Why not have a hidden field inside the form that mirrors the selection of the #selection option?

Comment: There are a couple options I can think of here. You could use JavaScript to get the value and store it in the form before submission. You could add a hidden variable to each form and pre-populate it with your desired value. You could also put the selectbox in the form and have it change the form it's in, instead of loading a whole new form.

Answer (score 0):

Add to each form a hidden input element:

```
<input type="hidden" name="selection" class="hiddenselection" />
```

Use javascript to copy the value on change. In jquery something like this:

```
$('#selection').on('change',function(){
     $('.hiddenselection').val($('#selection').val());
})
```

Comment: How can i send the value with the form when submitted?

Comment: Also hidden input types will send automatically when submit is triggered (e.g. click on submit-button).

Answer (score 0):

```
function showForm(value) {

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
         success: function(value){
                if(value =='iphone'){
                  $("#form2").hide();
                 }else{
                  $("#form1").hide();
                 }
                }
            });
}
```

Keep the selected value in hidden field form1 and form2

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="selection" onchange="showForm(this)">
<option value="iphone">iPhone</option>
<option value="Android">Android</option>
</select>

<form action="iphone.php" method="post" id="form1">
    <input type="text" name="username" required />
    <input type="hidden" name="selection" id="iphone_selection" />
</form>

<form action="android.php" method="post" id="form2">
    <input type="text" name="username" required />
    <input type="hidden" name="selection" id="android_selection" />
</form>

<script>
function showForm(THIS){
    var thisVal = $(THIS).val();
    if(thisVal == 'iphone'){
        $('#form2').hide();
        $('#form1').show();
        $('#iphone_selection').val(thisVal);
        //$("#form1").submit();        
    }
    if(thisVal == 'Android'){
        $('#form1').hide();
        $('#form2').show();
        $('#android_selection').val(thisVal);
        //$("#form2").submit();        
    }
}
</script>

<style>
#form1{
    display:none;
}
#form2{
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9tms99p5/

Answer (score -1):

Try to include this script on your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("selection").onchange();
    };

    function showForm(){
        if(document.getElementById("selection").value == "iphone"){
            document.getElementById("form1").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("form2").style.display = "none";
        }else if(document.getElementById("selection").value == "Android"){
            document.getElementById("form1").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("form2").style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>
```